# Python find longest ORF in DNA sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Can someone show me a straightforward solution for how to calculate the longest open reading frame (ORF) in a DNA sequence?  `ATG` is the start codon (i.e., the beginning of an ORF) and `TAG`, `TGA`, and `TAA` are stop codons (i.e., the end of an ORF).

Here's some code that produces errors (and uses an external module called BioPython):

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

currentCid = ''
buffer = []

for record in SeqIO.parse(open(sys.argv[1]),"fasta"):
    cid = str(record.description).split('.')[0][1:]

    if currentCid == '':
        currentCid = cid
    else:
        if cid != currentCid:
            buffer.sort(key = lambda x : len(x[1]))
            print '>' + buffer[-1][0]
            print buffer[-1][1]
            currentCid = cid
            buffer = [(str(record.description),str(record.seq))]
        else:
            buffer.append((str(record.description),str(record.seq)))

buffer.sort(key = lambda x : len(x[1]))
print '>' + buffer[-1][0]
print buffer[-1][1]
```

Is it possible to write this procedure with the least amount of external dependencies (or at least get the above code to work)?

Here's what my input looks like:

```
ACCGCCGCGAACATCGCCGAGATCCTGCCGCCGCAGCCGAGCCGGCTGGTCGAGTATGCGCAACGACGCG
CGTCCGGCAGCATCCCGGCGATCATGGCGCGCTGGGATGCACGCGTACTGCAGGACAACGAACCATTCAC
CGCAGTCTATGGCGGCGCGTCGTACATCAACAACGACCTGTTCCTCGCCCGCCTCGCCGACTGGGGCGTG
TCGGCCGGCAACTACAGCGGCGAGATCGGCGGCGCGACACCGCCGCTGCGCTGGCGCCCGCTGCGGCTGC
TGCGTTCGCTGCCGGTGTTCTGGCGCATGCTGCGTGTCGCGCGCGGGCACCTGCCGACGCTCGAGCGCGG
CTTGCAGCGCTTCGACCAGGAACTCGCGACGCTCGTCGAGCGACGCGCCGACGGCCAGCAACTGGCCGAC
TGGTTCACGCGCTTCTACGTGTTCGTCGTGCAGGGCAACCTGTGCATCGCGTCGTCGCTGGCCAGCAGCG
GCGGCGCACTGTGGGGCCGTCCGCCGACCGCATACGGCCAGCTCGACGACAGCCCGCACCGGCTGCCGTG
GGAAACCGATCCGGGCACCGCACGGCCCGCGCCCACCCACCTGCCGCTGCAGGCGTTTCCCGCCTGGCCG
CTGCCGGTCCGCGTGCTCCACGCGCTCGGCGCGCCCGGCATGCGCGGCTGGTATCTGCAGGTGCGCGAGT
GGTATCGCGACAACCTGATGCGCGTGTTCTTCCGCCTGCATCATGCGATGCCGGCCGCCGATCGCGACAC
GTGGTTCGCGCCCCATCCCGATCGCCGCGAACGCAACGGCAGCTTCTGGCAGGACGGCGGCGAAGGCACC
GACGAGGCAGCCGGCTTCATGATCTATCCGGGCCACACGCAAGGCGTGCTCGGCCACGACATCCTGCTGG
AAGACACGCTCGACCCGGGCCGGCACGCGCAGTACCAGGCCGCGCGCGCCGTGATCGCGCGCATGGGCGG
CCGGCTGTCGCACGGCGCGACGCTGCTGCGCGAGCTGCGCAAGCCGTCGGCCGTGCTGCCGCGCGTCGAT
GCGGCGTGGATCGGGCGCGAGGTGCGGCTCAGCGACGGCCAGCTGACGCTGGTCGAATGAACGCGATGCG
GTTGCCGCGCACCCGAGCACGGGCCCGGGCCTGAACTGCCGATCAGCGTACCGGCGTGCGGACGACTCCG
TCGACCTTCAGCGTGCGCCGGTCGTGCGCGGCTTCGTATTCGACCGTCTGCGCAGGCGTGACGGCGCCGT
ATGAATGGCCGTTCACGTAGACGGTGCCGTCCCGCAGCTCGACCCGGTCGCCGTTGACCGTCGCTGTGGC
CCGTTCACCCTGCAGCACCGCGCCCGAACAACCTGCAGTCGAAAAACTGCGGACCGACGTGCCCGGCATC
GCGGCGATCCCGCCCTGGTCCGCCGCATGCGCCGCGCTGCACGGCGGCGCATCCATGCTGCCGGCAGCGT
GGACCGCGCCGGCGCTGATGCCGCATCCGGCAAGCAGCGCAATCGTCATCGGCTTCAGATGGTTCATGGT
GAGCTCCGTTGTCCGCCGCCGCGGATCGATGACCGGCCGACGCCCGTGCTCGCATGGCAGGCCGGCCGGC
CGGATGCATCCAGTATGCGTCCGGTTCGCGGCATTCCGCCATCGTCGCCGATACCGCTCATCGCCGCCCG
GTTCGCTCCCGCAGCGGCCTCTGGAAGCACCTCCCGCGGGGCAACCCGTCCCCATGAAAATCCACCTTGA
TCAAGTTGCGACTCGCAACTATTATTGATTGCGATCCGCAACCTTTCCGGACCCGCCATGGACCTCATCG
ACGCTCCCGCCAAGCCCCGCGAAGCCACGATCCTCGAGCTGCGCGACTTCTCCCGCAAACTGGTTCGCGA
GCTCGGCTTCATGCGCGCGACGCTGGCCGACAGCGACTGGGCGCCTT
```

My output should be:

The longest substring that begins with `ATG` (i.e., the start of an ORF) and ends with either `TAG`, `TGA`, or `TAA` as stop codons (i.e., the end of an ORF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BioPython is a well-established and widely available module that's specifically designed for these sorts of questions, there's little reason to avoid it and re-invent the wheel. That said it is useful to use regexes to identify start codons:

```
from Bio import Seq
import regex as re
startP = re.compile('ATG')
nuc = input_seq.replace('\n','')
longest = (0,)
for m in startP.finditer(nuc, overlapped=True):
    if len(Seq.Seq(nuc)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)) > longest[0]:
        pro = Seq.Seq(nuc)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)
        longest = (len(pro), 
                   m.start(), 
                   str(pro),
                   nuc[m.start():m.start()+len(pro)*3+3])
```

Note that this uses the `regex` module, not the `re` module; the former allows easier identification of overlapping matches.  We can let BioPython count triplets and look for stop codons, rather than try to labor through regexes to do that.

Here, `longest` yields the length of the protein encoded by the ORF, the start site (note, using 0-based numbering), the protein sequence encoded by the ORF, and the sequence of the ORF itself, including the stop codon.

```
(338,
 93,
 'MARWDARVLQDNEPFTAVYGGASYINNDLFLARLADWGVSAGNYSGEIGGATPPLRWRPLRLLRSLPVFWRMLRVARGHLPTLERGLQRFDQELATLVERRADGQQLADWFTRFYVFVVQGNLCIASSLASSGGALWGRPPTAYGQLDDSPHRLPWETDPGTARPAPTHLPLQAFPAWPLPVRVLHALGAPGMRGWYLQVREWYRDNLMRVFFRLHHAMPAADRDTWFAPHPDRRERNGSFWQDGGEGTDEAAGFMIYPGHTQGVLGHDILLEDTLDPGRHAQYQAARAVIARMGGRLSHGATLLRELRKPSAVLPRVDAAWIGREVRLSDGQLTLVE',
 'ATGGCGCGCTGGGATGCACGCGTACTGCAGGACAACGAACCATTCACCGCAGTCTATGGCGGCGCGTCGTACATCAACAACGACCTGTTCCTCGCCCGCCTCGCCGACTGGGGCGTGTCGGCCGGCAACTACAGCGGCGAGATCGGCGGCGCGACACCGCCGCTGCGCTGGCGCCCGCTGCGGCTGCTGCGTTCGCTGCCGGTGTTCTGGCGCATGCTGCGTGTCGCGCGCGGGCACCTGCCGACGCTCGAGCGCGGCTTGCAGCGCTTCGACCAGGAACTCGCGACGCTCGTCGAGCGACGCGCCGACGGCCAGCAACTGGCCGACTGGTTCACGCGCTTCTACGTGTTCGTCGTGCAGGGCAACCTGTGCATCGCGTCGTCGCTGGCCAGCAGCGGCGGCGCACTGTGGGGCCGTCCGCCGACCGCATACGGCCAGCTCGACGACAGCCCGCACCGGCTGCCGTGGGAAACCGATCCGGGCACCGCACGGCCCGCGCCCACCCACCTGCCGCTGCAGGCGTTTCCCGCCTGGCCGCTGCCGGTCCGCGTGCTCCACGCGCTCGGCGCGCCCGGCATGCGCGGCTGGTATCTGCAGGTGCGCGAGTGGTATCGCGACAACCTGATGCGCGTGTTCTTCCGCCTGCATCATGCGATGCCGGCCGCCGATCGCGACACGTGGTTCGCGCCCCATCCCGATCGCCGCGAACGCAACGGCAGCTTCTGGCAGGACGGCGGCGAAGGCACCGACGAGGCAGCCGGCTTCATGATCTATCCGGGCCACACGCAAGGCGTGCTCGGCCACGACATCCTGCTGGAAGACACGCTCGACCCGGGCCGGCACGCGCAGTACCAGGCCGCGCGCGCCGTGATCGCGCGCATGGGCGGCCGGCTGTCGCACGGCGCGACGCTGCTGCGCGAGCTGCGCAAGCCGTCGGCCGTGCTGCCGCGCGTCGATGCGGCGTGGATCGGGCGCGAGGTGCGGCTCAGCGACGGCCAGCTGACGCTGGTCGAATGA')
```

Comment: What does the (0,) mean next to the 'longest' variable?

Comment: There is actually a bug here, because the translate method will return a translated sequence even if the passed nucleotide sequence has no STOP codon at all. Also, it is quite a slow implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into regular expressions:

```
import re

max(re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...)*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',s), key = len)
```

There is a good tutorial [here](http://pythonforbiologists.com/index.php/introduction-to-python-for-biologists/regular-expressions/), that focuses on the use of regular expressions with DNA strings

Comment: Wow, this is much more elegant than the solution I came up with :) (44 LOC)

Comment: Careful: `\w+` is "at least one letter (and some other things no one cares about)". For an ORF, you want triplets, and there's a pretty simple way to alter the regex to work. I'm not going to do it for you (I'm being lazy), but here's a link to an [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5rK7/1). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://www.kaggle.com/xiangma/orf-finder?scriptVersionId=6709465

As shown in the link above, there are two methods to do this:

Please note I set ORF length limitation above 1000bp and you can adjust it with your needs.

First one:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records = SeqIO.parse('dna2.fasta', 'fasta')
for record in records:
    for strand, seq in (1, record.seq), (-1, record.seq.reverse_complement()):
        for frame in range(3):
            length = 3 * ((len(seq)-frame) // 3)
            for pro in seq[frame:frame+length].translate(table = 1).split("*")[:-1]:
                if 'M' in pro:
                    orf = pro[pro.find('M'):]
                    pos = seq[frame:frame+length].translate(table=1).find(orf)*3 + frame +1
                    if len(orf)*3 +3 > 1300:
                        print("{}...{} - length {}, strand {}, frame {}, pos {}, name {}".format\
                           (orf[:3], orf[-3:], len(orf)*3+3, strand, frame, pos, record.id))
```

Second one, which uses the regex:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re
records = SeqIO.parse('dna2.fasta', 'fasta')

for record in records:
    for strand, seq in (1, record.seq), (-1, record.seq.reverse_complement()):
        for frame in range(3):
            index = frame
            while index < len(record) - 6:
                match = re.match('(ATG(?:\S{3})*?T(?:AG|AA|GA))', str(seq[index:]))
                if match:
                    orf = match.group()
                    index += len(orf)
                    if len(orf) > 1300:
                        pos = str(record.seq).find(orf) + 1 
                        print("{}...{} - length {}, strand {}, frame {}, pos {}, name {}".format\
                           (orf[:6], orf[-3:], len(orf), strand, frame, pos, record.id))
                else: index += 3
```